# Code doesn't work (please update title when you know what you're asking)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code will look through column A (skipping the header) and perform this evaluation:

- if the cell value is equal to the next cell value below it count it (a cell counts as 1 the value inside the cell is not relevant for this)
- if the cell value is not equal to the next cell value than perform this operation:

  ```
  ( 30 (this is a static number that won't change) - (whatever the cell count is at that point) = X
  ```
- insert X number of rows below the last cell that was equal. (so there is now X number of empty rows between the cells that are not equal.

***I think is next rule might be better to use at the very end which would be this operation:

- look for any blank cell in column A and fill in with the text "empty"
  ok this is basically what I'm trying to do but the code isn't functional

Code:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process, assuming headers
var startColumn = 1; // Last row of data to process
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
// Fetch the range of cells where data exist
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, lastRow, lastColumn)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
var data = dataRange.getValues();
var j = 0;
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var nextRow = data[i+1];
    var prevRow = data[i-1];
    var bin = row[1];
    var nextBin = nextRow[1];
    var prevBin = prevRow[1];
    if (oldBin == prevBin) {
        j++
        }
    if (nextBin != bin && nextBin != "empty" && j>=29) {
            var j = 0;
            }
        else if (nextBin != bin && nextBin != "empty") {
            sheet.insertRowAfter(i);
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(”empty") //marking the row as “empty"
            }
    } //End “for”
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here - in fact, there is no question expressed at all. Please edit the question with a new title and what ***specific problem*** you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding on your question:

1.You want to check the values from certain column(here it is A but your code refers to column B)

2.Compare each cell value with next row cell value. If the values are equal, increment a count or else insert no of rows equal to the count till now after the row if the count value is > 30 and make the count to 0.

3.Once you insert rows, add 'empty' value to the cells of newly inserted rows.

Please find the code below that finds the cells mismatching and inserts rows:

```
function countRows()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process, assuming headers
  var startColumn = 1; 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  // Fetch the range of cells where data exist
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, lastRow, lastColumn)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var j = 0, k = 0;
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++)
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var nextRow = data[i + 1];
    var bin = row[1];
    var nextBin = nextRow[1];

    if (bin == nextBin) {  j++    }
    else
    {
      rows.push([i+1,j]);
      j=0;
    }
}
  var temp =  1;
  for (i=0; i< rows.length; i++)
  {
    var data = rows[i];
    if(data[1] > 30){
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(data[0]+ temp, data[1]);
      temp += data[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Now all the rows are inserted. You just have to set the 'empty' string value to the inserted rows.

Hope that helps!